# post method flask

Tags: python, flask

Написал следующий код:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps

import xmlrpc.client as xm
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

srv = 'http://localhost:8069'
db = 'parser'
login = '1@1.ru'
pwd = '1'
class Labs(Resource):
    def post(self):
        global srv
        global db
        global login
        global pwd
        fgis_org_id = request.args.get('fgis_org_id', False)
        token = request.args.get('token', False)

        api = xm.ServerProxy('%s/xmlrpc/2/object' % srv)
        res = api.execute_kw(db, 1, pwd, 'fgis_parsing.lab', 'api_set_token', [fgis_org_id], {'fgis_org_id': fgis_org_id, 'token': token})
        return res
api.add_resource(Labs, '/parser/set_actual_token', methods=['POST'])
```

Когда перехожу по урлу `http://localhost:5002/parser/set_actual_token?fgis_org_id=32894&token=43` приходит сообщение `{"message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}` В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: И что вас смущает? Вы делаете запрос методом GET, а `Labs` отвечает только на POST.

Answer (score 3):

Перейти на сайт из браузера можно только методом `GET`. Ваше приложение отвечает на метод `POST`, соответственно при переходе через `GET` ничего не происходит.